# How to get the "You're in a meeting on another device" information from MS Teams via an API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When you join a MS Teams meeting on one client and open another desktop(!) client with the same user, it shows the following popup:

[image: MS Teams "You're in a meeting"]

**Is there any way to get this information from a web API(Graph, unofficial Teams, etc.)?**

Background:

We wanted to use the presence state "in a call", but this is not always accurate. For example when an appointment starts while you are in a call, the presence state changes to "in a meeting" despite you still being in a call. At this point, there is no way of knowing from the presence state, whether you are in a call.

Comment: When a meeting starts while the user is still in call and has not joined the meeting, the presence status will be updated as "in a meeting". That's current presence behavior.